# How can I use Multiple layouts with 404 page in React router

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a problem with multiple layouts in react routing and not found page

Main routs => with main layout

Admin routs => with admin layout

login page => without any layouts

404 page => without any layouts

My code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Redirect, Route, Switch } from 'react-router-dom';
import AuthContextProvider from './context/authContext/AuthContext';
```

```
const main = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Navbar />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/" exact component={Main} />
        <Route path="/contact" exact component={Contact} />
        <Route path="/about" exact component={About} />
        <Route path="/blog" exact component={Blog} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  )
}
```

```
const admin = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <PanelNavbar />
      <Switch>
        <Route path="/admin/panel" exact component={Panel} />
        <Route path="/admin/panel/menu" exact component={Menu} />
        <Route path="/admin/panel/blog" exact component={Blog} />
      </Switch>
    </div>
  )
}
```

```
const App = (props) => {
  return (
    <Router>
      <AuthContextProvider>
        <Switch>
          <Route path="/admin/login" exact component={Login} />
          <Route path='/admin' component={admin} />
          <Route path="/" component={main} />
          <Route path='/404' component={Page404} />
          <Redirect to='/404' />
        </Switch>
      </AuthContextProvider>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

I don't want 404 page to take any layouts.

I want just the wrong address to be redirected to a 404 page.

Please help me.

Thanks.

Comment: It would be create if you create a codesandbox. But I think you need exact on main and admin route of  App. Still a codesandbox would be lot helpful.

Answer (score 0):

you have to define a route for a 404 page like the below example:

```
<Route path='/404' component={Page404} />
<Redirect from='*' to='/404' />
```

then if the URL doesn't match with the defined routes, the user will be redirected to 404 page/route.

and about having a 404 page without any neighbor layout... that should be at the lowest layer and without my UI component neighbor, e.g:

```
function AppRoute({...params}) {
    return (
    <>
        <AnyComponentLikeNavBar />
        <Route {...params} />
    </>
    );
}

function App() {
    return (
    <BrowserRouter>
        <Switch>
            <AppRoute path="/" exact component={Main} />
            <AppRoute path="/contact" exact component={Contact} />
            <AppRoute path="/about" exact component={About} />
            <AppRoute path="/blog" exact component={Blog} />

            <Route path='/404' component={Page404} />
            <Redirect from='*' to='/404' />
        </Switch>
    </BrowserRouter>
    );
}
```